# Magento2 - Can't access RequireJS dependencies in certain function of overridden JS file

Tags: javascript, magento, knockout.js, requirejs, magento2

I'm working on Magento 2.1.7 and I'm facing a weird problem in my custom module.

I want to override Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.

I created a requirejs-config.js like this :

```js
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default" : "<my_vendor>/js/shipping-save-processor/default-override"
        }
    }
};
```

and the default-override.js like this :

```js
define(
        [
            'jquery',
            'underscore',
            'ko',
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager',
            'mage/storage',
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service',
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-converter',
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-billing-address'
        ],
        function ($,
                  _,
                  ko,
                  quote,
                  resourceUrlManager,
                  storage,
                  paymentService,
                  methodConverter,
                  errorProcessor,
                  fullScreenLoader,
                  selectBillingAddressAction) {
            'use strict';

            return {
                functionA: function () {
                    console.log(resourceUrlManager); //good => return object with all the function defined in the file Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager.js
                    this.functionB();
                },
                functionB: function () {
                    console.log(resourceUrlManager); // fail => Uncaught ReferenceError: resourceUrlManager is not defined
                }
          };
     });
```

I'm wondering why the dependency injection "works" only for my functionA and not in functionB when its called from functionA and how to solve it cleanly without passing resourceUrlManager by parameter to functionB.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution?